# Models and Interpretability

Tags: logic, model-theory, foundations

Is there any theorem that states that a theory $T'$ is interpretable in a theory $T$ if a model of $T'$ can also be made a model of $T$ or something like this?

What I'm asking is that is there a way one can infer interpretability of $T'$ in $T$ knowing something about their models?

Comment: What would be your definition of $T'$ is interpretable in $T$, and how does it relate to interpretability of a structure in an other?

Comment: I'm assuming the same definition of interpretability given by Tarski in his Undecidable Theories. That is,
$T'$ is interpretable in $T$ if there is a theory $T''$  and a set $D$ satisfying the following.
(1) $T''$ is an extension of both $T$ and $T'$ and its constants consist of the ones of $T$ and $T'$.
(2) $D$ is a recursive set of definitions of constants of $T'$ in $T$.
(3) Each constant of $T'$ occurs in only one sentence of $D$.
(4) Every sentence that is provable in $T''$ is also provable from a set of sentences of $T$ and the set $D$.

(By constant I mean non-logical constant.)

Comment: What do you mean "non-logical constants"?

Say $T$ and $T'$ are theories in the (disjoint) languages $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}'$ respectively. $D$ is a set of $\mathcal{L}\cup \mathcal{L'}$ formulas, right?

Comment: By non-logical constants, I mean the symbols in a theory that are not variables, connectives, or punctuation. So the non-logical constants of a theory consists of the relation, function, and individual constant symbols of the theory. 

Yes, $D$ is a set of $L\cup L′$ formulas.

Comment: My conjecture : if I find a model $M$ of $T$, a model $M'$ of $T'$ and a recursive interpretation, say $(f,n)$, of $M'$ in $M$, then we can build a set $D$ using $f$ such that the $\mathcal{L}\cup\mathcal{L}'$-theory of $M\sqcup M'$ together with $D$ will be an interpretation of $T'$ in $T$.

 What is your conjecture?

Comment: @OlivierRoche You have the quantifiers wrong in your conjecture: It should be *for all* models $M$ of $T$, and the interpretation of a model $M'$ in $M$ needs to be uniform in $M$ (in the sense that we fix a definition of each symbol in $L'$, which works to interpret a model $M'$ of $T'$ in every model $M$ of $T$).

Comment: @AlexKruckman No, I did mean what's written : implicitely, I need the structures $M$ and $M'$ to be recursively enumerable. From there, I hope to be able to construct $D$ In such a way that $T \cup D \vdash T'' := Th(M\cup M')$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche Well, then what you meant is wrong :)

Comment: @AlexKruckman Please prove me wrong! :)

Comment: I'm certainly not as experienced with this stuff as you guys are. I've defined this idea of what I took to call combinatorial containment, which I will lay out in the following comments. 

Let $(\textbf{D},M)$ and $(\textbf{D},M')$ be structures of languages $L_A$ and $L_B$, respectively (where A and B denote their sets of non-logical constants). Understand $A^M$ to be the set of all the images of members of $A$ under $M$, and let $B^{M'}$ be defined analogously. Furthermore, let rank($X$) be the number of entries of the members of $X\in A^M$ (similarly for $B^{M'}$).

Comment: Say that $(\textbf{D},M')$ is $\textbf{combinatorially contained}$ in $(\textbf{D},M)$ if there is a bijective map $\mu :\textbf{D}\to\textbf{D}$ and an injective map $\omega : B^{M'}\to A^M$ such that, for all $X\in A^M$, rank{$X$}=rank($\omega(X)$) and $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in X$ if and only if $(\mu(x_1),\mu(x_2),\dots,\mu(x_n))\in\omega(X)$, where rank($X$)$=n$.

Comment: My conjecture is: Let $T$ and $T'$ be theories in languages $L_A$ and $L_B$, respectively, that have models whose domain is a nonempty set $\textbf{D}$. If for all models $(\textbf{D},M)$ and $(\textbf{D},M')$ of $T$ and $T'$, respectively, $(\textbf{D},M')$ is combinatorially contained in $(\textbf{D},M)$, then $T'$ is interpretable in $T$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche The problem is that $T$ and $T'$ might not be complete theories. Take for example $T$ to be the theory of linear orders, and $T'$ to be the theory of dense linear orders. There is certainly *some* model $M\models T$ which interprets *some* model of $M\models T'$ (take $M = M' = \mathbb{Q}$), but $T'$ is not interpretable in $T$. Following the definition provided by jg2992, $D$ must consist only of the definition of $\leq$ as $\leq$ (since $T'$ does not add any new symbols to the language), and $T\cup D$ proves every sentence in $T''$, so (continued)

Comment: In fact $T$ proves every sentence in $T''$, so $T''$ is contained in the consequences of the theory of linear orders. But since $T'\subseteq T''$, this means that the theory of linear orders implies the theory of dense linear orders, which is absurd: there are linear orders which are not dense. This is why you need *every* model of $T$ to produce a model of $T'$, in order that $T$ is strong enough to prove all the axioms of $T'$ when augmented by the definitions $D$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Well done, thanks :)

Comment: @jg2992 I'd strongly recommend that you learn model theory and mathematical logic from modern sources (the Hodges textbook I recommend is a great place to learn model theory) and *then* go back and read the old classics. The terminology and clarity of ideas has improved a lot since Tarski's day. In particular, people (including me) are liable to be confused by talk of "non-logical constants", and by presenting a structure as $(\mathbf{D},M)$, where $M$ is an interpretation function. These things are very old-fashioned.

Comment: @jg2992 The way I understand it, your definition of "combinatorially contained" says that a structure $M'$ is combinatorially contained in a structure $M$ if $M'$ is isomorphic to the result of taking $M$, dropping some of the relation symbols in the language, and possibly renaming the other relation symbols. Not every interpretation looks like this. For example, if $T$ is the theory of linear orders, then $T$ interprets the theory $T'$ of [cyclic orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order#The_ternary_relation) in a language with a ternary relation symbol $R$, by (continued)

Comment: $R(x,y,z) \leftrightarrow ((x<y\land y<z)\lor (y<z\land z<x)\lor (z<x \land x<y))$. Of course, you don't have combinatorial containment of any cyclic order in any linear order, since the symbols in the language of linear orders and cyclic orders have different arities (I think you use the word *rank* instead of *arity*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare Tarski's definition of interpretability with the standard definition in model theory (see, e.g. Section 4.3 of *A Shorter Model Theory* by Hodges).

The definition is a bit complicated, so I'm not going to reproduce it here. But an interpretation of a theory $T'$ in a theory $T$ does correspond to a way of turning models of $T$ into models of $T'$ (note the reverse of direction) as described here: [Interpretation (model theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)). That is, $T'$ is interpretable in $T$ if and only if for every model $M\models T$, there is a model $M'\models T'$ such that $M'$ is interpretable in $M$, and these interpretations are uniform, in the sense that each of the definable sets specified in the definition are defined by the same $L$-formula in each model $M\models T$.

Tarski's definition as you reproduce it in the comments is stricter than the general model-theoretic definition on two ways. First, while the general model-theoretic definition allows the domain of the interpreted structure to be a quotient of a definable set in the original structure by a definable equivalence relation, Tarski requires the domain of the interpretable structure to be the same as the domain of the original structure. Second, Tarski requires the definitions (the set $D$) to be recursive. So in modern language, we might say that $T'$ is interpretable in $T$ in the sense of Tarski if $T'$ is a reduct of a recursive expansion by definitions of $T$. This is *stronger* than saying that $T'$ is interpretable in $T$, so it still corresponds to a way of turning models of $T$ into models of $T'$.

Namely, $T'$ is Tarski-interpretable in $T$ if and only if there is a recursive set of definitions for the symbols in $L'$ in terms of the symbols in $L$, such that if we take any model of $T$ and turn it into an $L'$-structure by using these definitions, we get a model of $T'$.